# How to split the message and receive element into WSO2 ESB 4.7.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

Hi i am receiving the file from remote server which in .csv format into wso2 ESB proxy service and i am getting the response as

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><text xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">firstname,lastname
a,John
b,Scott
c,Tiger
d,Manager
</text></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

but how can i split this message element by element and receive each element into ESB Proxy service.

Guide me how can i receive the split message into ESB and store into database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, you can use smooks mediator and convert CSV data to XML. Then data can be retrieved using XPath. There is a Stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915159/wso2-esb-file-processing-example-smooks-csv-parser-first-line-includes-payload-n) on this, Please go through it. Also you can use db report mediator to persist data in to preferred database. You find [doc](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Sample+361:+Introduction+to+dbreport+Mediator) from here. One you convert data to XML, then you can use XPath to define the data that must be persisted in to database. However, you can even write a custom medaitor for ESB,  if you want to do some more things than that. [Here](http://soasecurity.org/2013/11/28/how-to-wso2esb-how-to-write-custom-mediator/) it explains how to write a custom mediator